# CSS to see modal body as a block (PC & mobile phone)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to see the modal-body vertically align so it can be properly seen in a mobile phone as well as in a PC.

I am using bootstrap.

```html
<div class="modal-body" style="display: inline-block;">

  <div>
    <img class="product-photo-modal" src="" alt="" width="200" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <h3>Choose how many:</h1>
      <p class="product-info-modal" style="margin-right: 3px;"></p>
      <div>
        <button class="d-inline p-2 bg-primary text-white" id="substract-item-count" type="button">-</button>
        <p class="d-inline p-2" id="item-count">0</p>
        <button class="d-inline p-2 bg-primary text-white" id="add-item-count" type="button">+</button>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[image: Example of the output]

Comment: So your elements is already stacking vertically...

Comment: Bootstrap modals are already full-width on mobile. If you're asking about your interior structure, you'll need to be more clear. Please see [ask] for tips.

Comment: If the problem is the position of the image, add `text-center` to the modal body.

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered

> Add .modal-dialog-centered to .modal-dialog to vertically center the modal.

You don't have the  for the modal in your snippet so I'll assume it's outside:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">

</div>
```

This will make the modal appear vertically centered in the viewport (when opened on any size screen).